# Is it possible to check if const value is known at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Currently I am rewriting/extending my C++ utility library taking new C++11 features into account. One of the new additions is a template class which gives the maximum value of a set of numbers, hopefully at compile time.

```cpp
template<typename T, T... Xs> class ConstMax
{
private:
    template<typename... Ts> static constexpr T Max(Ts... xs);

    template<typename Tx> static constexpr T Max(Tx x)
    {
        return x;
    }

    template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts> static constexpr T Max(T1 x, T2 y, Ts... xs)
    {
        return y > x ? Max<T2, Ts...>(y, xs...) : Max<T1, Ts...>(x, xs...);
    }

public:
    static const T Value = Max(Xs...);
};
```

An example use of this class:

```cpp
int max = ConstMax<int, 1, 8, 66, 32, 90, 12, 33>::Value;
```

Here another example which might make it harder to verify if ConstMax<...>::Value was actually evaluated during compile time:

```cpp
template<typename... Ts> class Variant
{
public:
    static const size_t MaxValueSize = ConstMax<size_t, sizeof(Ts)...>::Value;
};
```

Which results in `max = 90`. I stepped trough this code using gdb and it seems there is no function call executed during the assignment of max.

My questions:

1. Can I safely assume that `ConstMax<...>::Value` is always known at compile time?
2. Is there a way to check if `constexpr` functions/methods are evaluated at compile time?
3. I understand members/methods/functions defined as `constexpr` are not necessarily evaluated during compile time, does the fact that `Value` is defined as being `static const` change anything about this or am I better off implementing this specific case as a recursive template class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Can I safely assume that ConstMax<...>::Value is always known at compile time?

Yes, since it's initialized with a constant expression. But I'd modify `Value` to be `constexpr` instead of just `const`.

> 2. Is there a way to check if constexpr functions/methods are evaluated at compile time?

Yes. Try using them in a `constexpr` expression. If it works, they're being evaluated at compile time. If it fails to compile, then it's not being evaluated at compile time.

> 3. I understand members/methods/functions defined as constexpr are not necessarily evaluated during compile time, does the fact that Value is defined as being static const change anything about this or am I better off implementing this specific case as a recursive template class?

If you use the members in a constant expression, you're forcing them to be evaluated at compile time. So if you cared, I'd just make sure to evaluate them in constant expressions (via `constexpr`).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I did fancy the constexpr approach more then using recursive templates, good to know this doesn't affect the time of evaluation.

Comment: How can you tell if a function is constexpr at compile time by calling it? If one of the arguments isnt constexpr the call will fail as well right?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, if you try to evaluate the function in a constant expression, and it is not a constant expression, compilation will fail.

Comment: @Cornstalks can you conclude that the error comes from the function definition and not from the argument definition?

Answer (score 4):

To check if an expression is `constexpr` (i.e., constant expression) you could use `std::integral_constant` type trait as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, T... Xs> class ConstMax {
  template<typename... Ts> static constexpr T Max(Ts... xs);
  template<typename Tx> static constexpr T Max(Tx x) { return x;}
  template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
  static constexpr T
  Max(T1 x, T2 y, Ts... xs) {
        return y > x ? Max<T2, Ts...>(y, xs...) : Max<T1, Ts...>(x, xs...);
  }
public:
    static const T Value = Max(Xs...);
};

int main() {
 std::cout << std::integral_constant<int, ConstMax<int, 1, 8, 66, 32, 90, 12, 33>::Value>::value << std::endl;   
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8286cec4215ab285)

If it's not `constexpr` it will break the compilation process.

Comment: Thank you, this will become a really nice extension to my unit tests.